# Apportion row to other rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a simple way to apportion rows to another row?

I want to split the Unknown country between all other countries. In this example 2 countries.
`For a given date, UK = UK + (UK*Unknown)/sum(UK + US)`

```
E.g. UK = 1 + (1*5)/(1+7) = 1 + 5/8 = 1.625
```

```
df
  date       country col1  col2 
2019-12-20    UK      1    10
2019-12-20    Unknown 5    20
2019-12-20    USA     7    30
...
```

```
Expected Output

 df
  date       store     col1    col2 
2019-12-20    UK      1.625    15
2019-12-20    USA     11.375   45
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `groupby` to figure out how much 'Unknown' you have on a given date and how much you have in all other countries. Make sure to `.fillna(0)` incase there is a date without any 'Unknown' so that the math works later without leading to `NaN`. Then we can merge that information back and perform the calculation.

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
df1 = df.groupby(['date', df.country.eq('Unknown')])[cols].sum().unstack(-1).fillna(0)
df1.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in df1.columns]
#            col1_False  col1_True  col2_False  col2_True
#date                                                    
#2019-12-20           8          5          40         20

# Bring over values and remove Unknown rows
df = df.merge(df1, on='date').query('country != "Unknown"')
#         date country  col1  col2  col1_False  col1_True  col2_False  col2_True
#0  2019-12-20      UK     1    10           8          5          40         20
#2  2019-12-20     USA     7    30           8          5          40         20

# Calculate and then drop helper columns
for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col]*(1+df[f'{col}_True']/df[f'{col}_False'])
    
df = df.drop(columns=[x for x in df.columns if 'True' in x or 'False' in x])
```

---

```
         date country    col1  col2
0  2019-12-20      UK   1.625  15.0
2  2019-12-20     USA  11.375  45.0
```